# How to animate a window with Processing?

Tags: processing

I am using [Processing](http://processing.org/) to learn programming and wondered if there is a way to make an OS window grow, shrink, make it transparent or give it round edges. As far as I know Processing uses Java's Frame class and not the JFrame class, but I just can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks for your help.

*For reference, similar question asked at* [Re: Forcing a window to stay in front of all other - Reply #3](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb_beta/YaBB.cgi?board=Programs;action=display;num=1228732953)

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as solution if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 9):

For resizing the window simply use the following command in your `draw()` method:

```
frame.setSize(x,y);
```

Make sure you define the frame as resizable in your `setup()` method:

```
frame.setResizable(true);
```

Using plain vanilla processing you can't change other window attribute as they are part of the frame the framework draws for you. I suppose if you hack processing a bit in a regular IDE, such as eclipse, you could somehow override this behavior and draw a window/frame of your own.

Comment: works awesome. Haven't been playing with these attributes but always was wondering if it's possible to change alter them :)